# MySQL: Selecting rows ordered by word count

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

How can I order my query by word count? Is it possible?

I have some rows in table, with text fields. I want to order them by word count of these text fields.

Second problem is, that I need to select only these rows, which have for example minimum 10 words, or maximum 20.

Comment: So you're really looking for a function `F` such that `F('Where is pancakes house?')` will return 4?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for it, but as I see now, there is no good workaround so I will have to add another column with word count for this field, and then it will be simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this will not perform very well since string calculations need to be performed for *all* rows:

You can count number of words in a MySQL column like so: `SELECT SUM( LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))+1) FROM table` (provided that words are defined as "whatever-delimited-by-a-whitespace")

Now, add this to your query:

```
SELECT
    <fields>
FROM
    <table>
WHERE
    <condition>
ORDER BY SUM(LENGTH(<fieldWithWords>) - LENGTH(REPLACE(<fieldWithWords>, ' ', '')) + 1)
```

Or, add it to the condition:

```
SELECT
    <fields>
FROM
    <table>
WHERE
    SUM(LENGTH(<fieldWithWords>) - LENGTH(REPLACE(<fieldWithWords>, ' ', '')) + 1) BETWEEN 10 AND 20
ORDER BY <something>
```

Comment: Since I asked about query then your answer is ok. But of course I will not use this approach because of heavy string calculations.

Comment: `SUM` should not be used at all.  simply use `SELECT LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))+1`

Comment: Oh well I see OP says "text fields" pluarl, so I can see how SUM would be needed is adding all fields word count together.  but the examples above imply a single field which is why i got confused.  So to clarify my above comment, SUM is indeed needed if checking total word count of more than one column.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT Field1, SUM( LENGTH(Field2) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Field2, ' ', ''))+1)
 AS cnt
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Field1
ORDER BY cnt
```

`Field2` is the string field in which you'd like to count words.

Comment: It could work - thanks, but I realized that string operations will be to heavy for db adapter and its faster to count words right at the insertion.